# gmail labels, VBA CDO

Tags: vba, ms-access, gmail-api, cdo.message

In VBA (Access) in a CDO routine, I want to attach a custom gmail label programmatically to a particular e-mail.

I can specify a subject line using the line Mail.Subject = "My Subject", but how can I attach one of my custom labels to my e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add labels to a message. It is up to the receiver to change labels to his liking.

If you are sending a message to the user himself, you could [**modify**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) the message after you send it:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{message_id}/modify?access_token={access_token}

{
 "addLabelIds": [
  {label_id}
 ]
}
```